# If I want to use "bountying" in a sentence, how might I construct a spelling for it? If not possible, what word could be used instead?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography

*I frequently add bounties to Stack Exchange questions. I do a lot of bountying. I find [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46375/12102) fascinating and in need of bountying, but alas, I do not know how to attempt to spell bountying and searching high and low I can not find a spelling.*

> Answering may require some extensive research, and I'm really interested in seeing it, so bountying.

It seems that the verb form of bounty might not exist or at least be popular. If I nonetheless want to use it in a sentence, how might I construct a spelling for it? [Iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) no such spelling is possible, what single word replacement would work in the examples above?

No verb form found on the following pages:

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounty
- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bounty
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bounty
- https://www.lexico.com/definition/bounty
- https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bounty

Comment: Well, "bountying" is probably the best you can do.  Unless you go for "bounticizing" or some such.

Comment: Or *bountify*..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could always say that *you post* (or *award*) *a lot of bounties*. This seems the most natural way to express it.

But if you’re still looking to make *bounty* into a verb via zero-conversion, it might interest you to know that it doesn’t have a common phonetic pattern for ending verbs with. Indeed, English has no verbs at all that rhyme with *bounty*, and it has only two that end in *‑nty* at all, neither of which is in common use.

English doesn’t even have all that very many that end in *‑ty* either, but some of those in common use are *pity*, *empty*, and *dirty*, and rather less formally the twencen American colloquial
verb *party* meaning any or all of attending a party, having a good time, or partaking in recreational drugs, is probably well known by now.

In any event, there is no question of how the putative verb’s *-ing* inflection should be spelled, as these are all perfectly regular, even *crying, plying, pitying, partying, buoying, conveying, reifying, quaying*. It’s not like *money* and *monied*.

That leaves you with the same *bountying* you started with, if that’s your druther.  All *‑ing* verbs are perfectly regular, at least phonetically. Occasionally orthographic tweaks are needed, as in *betting, braking, dying, eying, picnicking*.